# How to get the text of cluster centers from scikit-learn KMeans?

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, scikit-learn

I have a list of strings that I use to fit `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`:

```python
X = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(docs)
km = KMeans().fit(X)
```

Now I would like to get the cluster centers in their original string representation. I know `km.cluster_centers_` but could not figure out how to get the relevant indices of `docs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "original representation" of the cluster centers in *k*-means; they are not actually points (vectorized documents) from the input set, but means of multiple points. Such means cannot be transformed back into documents since the bag-of-words representation destroys the order of terms.

One possible approximation is to take a centroid vector, then use `TfidfVectorizer.inverse_transform` on it to find out which terms have non-zero tf-idf value in it.

You could achieve what you want with the [*k*-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) algorithm, which does assign actual input points as centroids, but that is not implemented in scikit-learn.

Comment: You could use the Affinity Propagation algorithm, that returns actual data points as cluster centers, also.

Comment: @cjohnson318: good point. I've never tried that algorithm on text, though.

Comment: @larsmans: Thanks for clarifying and the pointer to _k_-medoids!

Comment: @larsmans: I just found out about it, so it's my New Favorite Algorithm to apply to everything. I like it because you don't need to know how many clusters you're looking for, but for this application, specifying the number of clusters a priori might be more appropriate. I'm not sure.

Comment: @mathias But since KMeans does return the centroids, you can just calculate the Euclidean distance from each point in your data set to each center and then return the actual data points closest to the centroids.